# How make multiple replace with SQL Server - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, replace

I am doing replaces of some texts (Mask) of a column of a temporary table. I am replacing the searchable text with a column of tables.

Example:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
INTO TEMP_COMPL_L 
FROM TB_CONTRATO 
WHERE IDCAR_CON = 1

ALTER TABLE TEMP_COMPL_L 
    ADD COMPL_TMP VARCHAR(1500)

UPDATE TEMP_COMPL_L 
SET COMPL_TMP = '#FIRSTNAME#, URGENTE: Va a sua loja no dia #DATE# e procure o Gerente #MANAGERNAME#.'

-- GET DATAS FROM MASKS HERE
UPDATE TEMP_COMPL_L 
SET COMPL_TMP = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COMPL_TMP,
                               '#FIRSTNAME#', LEFT(NOME_CLI, CHARINDEX(' ',NOME_CLI)-1)),
                               '#MANAGERNAME#', ISNULL(CONTT_LOJ,'')),
                               '#DATE#', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
    )
FROM TEMP_COMPL_L 
INNER JOIN TB_CLIENTE ON IDCLI_TMP = IDCLI_CLI
LEFT JOIN TB_LOJA ON IDLOJ_TMP = IDLOJ_LOJ
```

That way it works perfectly, however, I will need to do this for more than 20 possible masks informed by the client, taking the mask and giving a replace for the value of the corresponding column in the table LOJA and CLIENTE.

Is there a way to leave with a better performance and visibly readable? Because several replaces will be very confused. In addition to having a limit of replaces allowed in SQL Server.

Comment: Nested replace is super fast and there is no limit to number that you can use. It can become challenging to format it legibly but it looks you have a great pattern started for that already.

Comment: I thought I had a nesting limit. I'll see it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get better performance than nested replaces.

If you want to make it more readable, you could put the replaces in a UDF, but that might cause a small performance hit.

Comment: I imagine doing it by function would lose performance. I can't have both, performance and readability..  :(

Answer (score 0):

For performance, there may not be any better solution than using a nested replace. But for readable purpose you can re-write as below

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * 
INTO TEMP_COMPL_L 
FROM TB_CONTRATO 
WHERE IDCAR_CON = 1

ALTER TABLE TEMP_COMPL_L 
    ADD COMPL_TMP VARCHAR(1500)

DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)

-- GET DATAS FROM MASKS HERE
;With DataMask AS
(
    SELECT  T.IDCLI_CLI
            ,ISNULL(T.NOME_CLI,'#FIRSTNAME#')       as First_Name
            ,ISNULl(L.CONTT_LOJ,'#MANAGERNAME#')    as Manager_Name
    FROM        TB_CLIENTE  T
    LEFT JOIN   TB_LOJA     L
    ON          T.IDLOJ_TMP = L.IDLOJ_LOJ
)

UPDATE  TMP
SET     COMPL_TMP   = D.First_Name + ', URGENTE: Va a sua loja no dia ' + @date + ' e procure o Gerente ' + Manager_Name + '.'
FROM    TEMP_COMPL_L    TMP
JOIN    DataMask        D
ON      TMP.IDCLI_TMP   = D.IDCLI_CLI
```